# Getting a single element with `getElementsByTagName`

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbytagname

I know that if we want to find a group of elements, getElementsByTagName is the method for us and it returns a NodeList. but if we are looking for tag name with "body" , then why we need to add [0] after the ("body") element? There is only one body tag in an HTML document.

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 body.className = "unreadable";
```

why we cant write  this code without index[0] like this

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
 body.className = "unreadable";
```

If i write this code the class unreadable will not be added with body tag ...why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName` allways returns NodeList. If you want find easier way to retrieve body you can use just `document.body`

Answer (score 3):

[`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) **always** returns a `NodeList`. It does not matter whether an element with a certain tag exists only once.

It would be bad if the function behaved inconsistently.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` returns  a NodeList. It might have no items in it. It might have one. It might have many. You can see how many are in it by testing its `.length`.

It would be confusing if it sometimes returned a NodeList and sometimes returned an ElementNode.